# React hooks show more/less text like in youtube comments section

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have some array of comments like in youtube comments section and i wan't to make it show less/more button for long comment. I've stuck a little on a way to do it locally on item without total rerender (rebuild of block) or any states values.

```
function commentsGenerate() {
    let block = comments.map((comment, i) => {
        let splitLength = 400
        let shortDesc = comment || '' // for null vals

        let shortened = false
        if (shortDesc.length > splitLength) shortened = true

        shortDesc = shortDesc.substring(0, splitLength)

        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <div>{`${shortDesc}${shortened ? '...' : ''}`}</div>
            {shortened && <Button onCLick={ () => {'how?'} >More</Button>}
          </div >
        )
      })


    setSectionBlock(block)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't/shouldn't do this sort of thing without using state somewhere. In this case I suggest that you separate your comment code and state into a separate component which can handle its own expanded state. You can then use the state to adjust the rendering and styling of your output:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

// ... //

const Comment = ({comment:shortDesc = ''})=>{
    let splitLength = 400
    let shortened = false
    const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false)
    if (shortDesc.length > splitLength) shortened = true

    shortDesc = shortDesc.substring(0, splitLength)
    const handleToggle = ()=>{
        setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)
    }
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        {!isExpanded ? <div>{`${shortDesc}${shortened ? '...' : ''}`}</div> : null}
        {shortened && <Button onClick={handleToggle}>{isExpanded?'Less':'More'}</Button>}
      </div >
    )
  }
```

Use this component in your mapping like this:

```
 let block = comments.map((comment, i) => <Comment comment={comment} key={i} /> )
```